# testthat.R directory paths

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm trying out the R package structure for a data analsysis project - i.e. one that is used entirely through `devtools::load_all()`, rather than `library(mypackage)`.

When I use this structure, all of my tests reference their directory, instead of the project root directory, for example:

```
test_that("Load some data",{
  df <- readr::read_csv('data/someData.csv')
})
```

This code failes, because the `test_that` function reads from the file's directory ("tests/testthat/data/someData.csv"), rather than the current or project directory. I could set the directory within each instance of `test_that`, but I'd rather avoid the redundancy of doing so. Is there any way that I can run these files from the testthat.R file where they'll reference the correct directroy?

Comment: I think you need to put the path into the `test_path()` function

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've been doing. I was hoping for a solution where I wouldn't have to manually insert into dozens of tests.